# Returning from a function by reference (PHP5)

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

Why doesn't this program work as expected? I read a PHP5 book, which writes that the following program should result in `25`; I get `15`.

```
function numberPlus($number){
    $number += 5;
    return $number;
}

$oldNumber = 10;
$returnNumber = &numberPlus($oldNumber);
$oldNumber += 10;
echo $returnNumber;
```

Comment: improved formatting + proper tags for visibility

Answer (score 0):

'Cause you are printing returned number by that function. This might be what you want:

```
function numberPlus(&$number){
    $number += 5;
}

$oldNumber = 10;
numberPlus($oldNumber);
$oldNumber += 10;
echo $oldNumber; // 25
```

Comment: Hmm, not quite.

Your mode works because you are referenceing for a variable, but I want to reference for a function. So I want to call the function and after that I change the variable's value (without &$number).

All the same. I suppose that the book is too old (2005).

However, thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

A function in PHP can return a reference by adding `&` to its name as:

```
function &function_name($params)
{
    ...
}
```

You must also call this function with `&`:

```
$var = &function_name(...);
```

However, notice the reference must be valid after the function ends, or it won't work. If the function returns a reference to one of its local variables, this variable will be destroyed the moment the function terminates and `$var` will be `null`.

In order to work, this function will have to return global variables, properties of the same object in case they are methods of a class, or parameters that are also references.

In your case, you would have to do something like:

```
function &numberPlus(&$number) // param is reference
{
    $number += 5;
    return $number;
}

$a = 10; // 10
$b = &numberPlus($a); // $a == $b == 15
$b += 10; // $a == $b == 25
```

Comment: Yes, I want to get this result. Thank you very much! :)